# Spring MVC Unit Test - how to use hamcrest matcher

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to write a simple test case for an MVC controller method.

I want to test the view name contains a string.

I think I need this version of the name matcher:

`public ResultMatcher name(org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super String> matcher)`
Taken from here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/ViewResultMatchers.html#name-org.hamcrest.Matcher-

But how do I use it? I can't work out the right syntax...

(syntax error on the Matchers.contains("web_tmpl") part of this expression:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/content/2"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name(Matchers.contains("web_tmpl")))
            ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a static import for

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
```

and use

```
.andExpect(view().name(containsString("web_tmpl")))
```

if you're using maven the dependency is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: you welcome, static import just helps with the code clutter, the main point is the cointainsString, glad it helped